# Creating multiple TextBoxes based on user input

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, textbox, user-input

Hy guys,

I am doing an desktop app in UWP using C#.

And I want to create **unknow** text boxes based on user input.

For example let's say that I have TextBox and OkButton on **Page1** the user have to type number in text box and than press the OkButton. After that the app will navigate to the another page (let's call it **Page 2**) which will has as many text boxes as the input of user was.

For an instance user will type 5 into the TextBox on the **Page1** than he will press the button, the App will navigate to the **Page2** and it will contain 5 TextBoxes ready for another input

Here is an example source code

Page1.xaml

```
<Grid>
 <TextBox x:Name="UserInput" Margin="558,459,557,459" Header="UserInput"/>
 <Button x:Name="DoneButton" Height="29" Width="95" Margin="558,565,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Done" Click="DoneButton_Click"/> </Grid>
```

Page1.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DoneButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      (App.Current as App).UserInput =  Convert.ToInt32( UserInput.Text); // this will store userinput data in the global app variable
                                                                          // variable so I can work with that later
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
    }
```

Page2.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Here I want to create text boxes based on user input" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30"/>
</Grid>
```

Page2.xaml.cs

```
 public sealed partial class Page2 : Page
{
    public Page2()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int UserInput = (App.Current as App).UserInput; //storing global app variable to work with it later

    //here I want to crate multiple text boxes
}
```

Thank you guys for your valuable time and answers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Creating multiple TextBoxes based on user input

You could pass page1's number of textbox to page2 with `Navigate` method, then generate matched count of textbox in page2

For example

**page1**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox x:Name="Number" />
    <Button
        x:Name="MyBtn"
        Click="Button_Click"
        Content="Generate" />
</StackPanel>

.......

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(AddPage), Number.Text);
}
```

**Page2**

```
<StackPanel x:Name="RootLayout" Orientation="Vertical" />

......

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (e.Parameter != null && e.Parameter.ToString() != string.Empty)
    {
        var count = Convert.ToInt32(e.Parameter);
      
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 15, 0);
            RootLayout.Children.Add(textbox);
           
        }
      
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so kindly :)

It really worked just as excepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void cr(int numberoftextboxes)
{
    int x = 10;  // < --your starting x coordinate(will stay the same if you want your textboxes stacked horizontally.
    int y = 10;  // < --your starting y coordinate
    int h = 20;  // < --textbox height
    int w = 100; // < --textbox width
    int s = 15;  // < --spacing

    for (int c = 0; c < numberoftextboxes; c++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Name = "Your TextBox name";
        tb.Text = "Your TextBox Text";
        tb.Size = new Size(w, h);
        Page2.Controls.Add(tb);
        tb.Location = new Point(x, y);
        y = y + h + s;
    }
}
```

if you create Page2 from the button click, you can place the call to cr() in the constructor of Page2.

```
public sealed partial class Page2 : Page
{
    public Page2()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        cr();
    }

    public int UserInput = (App.Current as App).UserInput; //storing global app variable to work with it later

    private void cr(int numberoftextboxes)
    ....
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but when I was trying it the tb.Location is not existing.
I was trying to find some solutions but I din't.

Comment: No worries. I see that you accepted Nico Zhu's solution which is much more elegant and complete.